# Исключение java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError в org/apache/logging/log4j/LogManager

Tags: java, log4j

Подскажите, в чем причина исключения

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/logging/log4j/LogManager
        at ru.sfedu.SchoolMeals.SchoolClient.<clinit>(SchoolClient.java:14)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
```

Код:

```
public class SchoolClient {
    private static Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(SchoolClient.class);

    public SchoolClient(){
        log.debug("<ConstructorName>[0]: starting application.........");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        new SchoolClient();
        logBasicSystemInfo();
    }
    public static void logBasicSystemInfo() throws IOException {
        log.info("Launching the application...");
        ...
    }
```

Comment: `ClassNotFoundException` как и `NoClassDefError` чаще всего указывают на то, что в коде есть класс, "описание" которого в момент компиляции было, и всё прекрасно скомпилировалось, а в момент запуска уже нет такого "описания" класса. Смотрите classpath, есть ли в не в момент запуска jar-ка с log4j.

Comment: нет, jar файла с log4j нет. А должен быть?

Comment: ну Вы же используете в коде `org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager`, значит должен быть.

Comment: что же делать?..

Comment: fatJar (один jar со всеми зависимостями внутри) можно собрать и его запускать. Можно jlink для сборки использовать. Вариантов масса.